# Is it possible to disable implicit connection cache while using connection pooling in Oracle OAS?

Tags: connection, database, cache

Hi we are using implicit connection cache under Oracle Application Server (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/oc4j-ds-083633.html). I am not a system guy, I am just a programmer but I just wonder if it is possible to disable implicit connection cache while using a connection pool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the information about how to disable implicit connection cace while using connection pool in this link : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/oc4j-ds-083633.html